# while loop behavior, how expression is evaluated

Tags: php, while-loop

If the following line of code causes php to consume 100% of the cpu time

```
 while(true){}
```

then why should the following code not do the same? after all, `!feof($fp)` is just a boolean expression, and when evaluating as true, it uses no perceivable cpu time at all.

```
 $fp = stream_socket_client($remote_socket);
 while(!feof($fp)){}
```

Comment: while(true){} will never be false. while(!feof($fp)){} will be initially false then true at some point.

Comment: `while(true){}` simply loops, with no interruptable processing, so it will hammer your CPU; `while(!feof($fp)){}` has an actual filestream test to execute, so it is interruptible, and the processor will behave accordingly

Comment: This will also depend on what the loop is doing. `while(true){}` does no operations, so the entire CPU is used running the loop. Your other statement has to wait for a load of other things to occur - and your CPU isn't being used at this time while it is waiting for the rest to happen.

Comment: Do you actually have anything inside the loop in both cases? I'd expect both to consume 100% CPU if the body is empty.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I tested with this exact code the second loop as far as I can see uses 0% of the cpu

Answer (score 0):

This is about how much work goes on in the loop before the loop condition is evaluated again, and for how long that condition will remain true.

`while(true){}` Nothing to evaluate and forever. So 100%

```
While(true) 
{
  // Wait 1 second for a key press
  // Display another '.'
}
```

loop still runs forever, but there's a 'pause' of one second every execution of the loop.

Your example given eof is and remains true it will never exit, but checking eof takes some time, so it won't be a 100%, be fairly close though I should think...

Comment: `be fairly close though I should think...` see thats what I would have thought, but the truth is it barely causes a blip in the cpu usage

Comment: `while(true){} Nothing to evaluate and forever. So 100%`. Actually it evaluates the explicit version: `while (true == true) {}` which still is a valid expression. Maybe you meant to say "nothing to compare" ?

Comment: @andrew, if it barely causes a blip feof is false. That's the equivalent of while(false){} which wouldn't give you a 100% either...